# Scala convert List[Int] to a java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

Is there a way in `Scala` to convert a `List[Int]` to `java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]`?

I'm interfacing with Java (Thrift).

`JavaConversions` supports `List --> java.util.List`, and implicits exist between `Int --> java.lang.Integer`, but from what I can tell I would still need an extra pass to manually do the conversion:

```
val y = List(1)     
val z: java.util.List[Integer] = asList(y)  map { (x: Int) => x : java.lang.Integer }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently you need both conversions. However, you can group them in a single implicit conversion:

```
implicit def toIntegerList( lst: List[Int] ) =
  seqAsJavaList( lst.map( i => i:java.lang.Integer ) )
```

Example:

```
scala> def sizeOf( lst: java.util.List[java.lang.Integer] ) = lst.size

scala> sizeOf( List(1,2,3) )
res5: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 25):

Because the underlying representation of Int is Integer you can cast directly to `java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]`. It will save you an *O(n)* operation and some implicit stuff.

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

class A {
  def l() = asList(List(1,2)).asInstanceOf[java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]]
}
```

Then you can use from Java like this:

```
A a = new A();
java.util.List<Integer> l = a.l();
```

*Note that on 2.9.0 ,I get a deprecation warning on `asList` (use `seqAsJavaList` instead)*

Comment: This seems the most correct answer. Still relevant with `scala.collection.convert.decorateAsJava` as of 2014 with Scala 2.11.1.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try:

```
val javalist = collection.JavaConversions.asJavaList (y)
```

I'm not sure, whether you need a conversion Int=>Integer or Int=>int here. Can you try it out?

**Update:**
The times, they are a changing. Today you'll get a deprecated warning for that code. Use instead:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val y = List (1)
> y: List[Int] = List(1)

val javalist = (y).asJava
> javalist: java.util.List[Int] = [1]
```

Comment: It appears it does not actually convert the underlying type, at least Idea gives me type errors.

Comment: I only get a warning today but it is still working - 2 years after answering: `warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
javalist: java.util.List[Int] = [1]`. Today you would use JavaConverters. I update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have an implicit at the outmost layer, but I like this generic approach and have implemented it for a couple of types of collections (List, Map).

```
import java.util.{List => JList}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  def scalaList2JavaList[A, B](scalaList: List[A])
                              (implicit a2bConversion: A => B): JList[B] =
    (scalaList map a2bConversion).asJava
```

Since an implicit conversion from Int to Integer is part of standard lib, usage in this case would just look like this:

```
  scalaList2JavaList[Int, Integer](someScalaList)
```

### In the other direction!

(since I have these available anyway as they were my original implementations...)

```
import java.util.{List => JList}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

  def javaList2ScalaList[A, B](javaList: JList[A])
                              (implicit a2bConversion: A => B): List[B] =
    javaList.toList map a2bConversion
```

Usage:

```
  javaList2ScalaList[Integer, Int](someJavaList)
```

This can then be re-used for all lists so long as an implicit conversion of the contained type is in scope.

(And in case you're curious, here is my implementation for map...)

```
  def javaMap2ScalaMap[A, B, C, D](javaMap: util.Map[A, B])(implicit a2cConversion: A => C, b2dConversion: B => D): Map[C, D] =
    javaMap.toMap map { case (a, b) => (a2cConversion(a), b2dConversion(b)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library includes [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) which provides Scala to Java implicit collection conversions.

Which we can combine with `java.lang.Integer::valueOf` to convert Scala's `Int` to Java's `Integer`:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

List(1, 2, 3).map(Integer.valueOf).asJava
// java.util.List[Integer] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pass a `Map[String, Double]` to a Java method. But the problem was `JavaConversions` converts the `Map` to a java `Map`, but leaves the scala `Double` as is, instead of converting it to `java.lang.Double`. After a few hours of seaching I found [Alvaro Carrasco's answer])https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683561/1612432), it is as simple as doing:

```
val scalaMap = // Some Map[String, Double]
val javaMap = scalaMap.mapValues(Double.box)
```

After this, `javaMap` is a `Map[String, java.lang.Double]`. Then you can pass this to a java function that expects a `Map<String, Double>` and thanks to implicit conversions the Scala Map will be converted to `java.util.Map`

In your case would be the same, but with `Int.box`:

```
val y = List(1)
val javay = y.map(Int.box)
```