# Use functions from a Scala object that have implicit parameters in java code

Tags: java, json, scala, implicit, scala-java-interop

Is there a way that I can use the `fromJson` and `toJson` methods in my java code? I would want to call it to transform a bson document that I get from mongoldb to a model class that I have in Scala

My Scala object is below,

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.{DefaultScalaModule, ScalaObjectMapper}

object JsonUtils {

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper

  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def toJson(value: Map[Symbol, Any]): String = {
    toJson(value map { case (k,v) => k.name -> v})
  }

  def toJson(value: Any): String = {
    mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
  }

  def toMap[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]) = fromJson[Map[String,V]](json)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }

  implicit class Marshallable[T](marshallMe: T) {
    def toJson: String = JsonUtils.toJson(marshallMe)
  }

  implicit class Unmarshallable(unMarshallMe: String) {
    def toMap: Map[String,Any] = JsonUtils.toMap(unMarshallMe)
    def fromJson[T]()(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T =  JsonUtils.fromJson[T](unMarshallMe)
  }
}
```

Comment: That Scala code is just a thin wrapper over the Java Jackson library. Why not call that directly? Or alternately, write the code that goes from BSONObject -> Scala case class instance in Scala as well. That method will then have a much simpler signature and be easier to call from Java.

Comment: As an experiment I did try what you said on the scala case class conversion and yes it is simpler. I was also looking to reuse more of my scala libraries that were created. Is it by design that scala -> java is more annoying than java to scala? Sorry I might have missed out how much java and scala have evolved. I've mostly been on the kernel side of things

Comment: @AdiKish Hardly Java and Scala were evolving trying to make interop Scala -> Java more annoying than vice versa. Just Scala has more features than Java so in the case of Java -> Scala interop you have better chances that those features are naturally expressible than vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java code you have to resolve Scala implicits manually.

Try to call `fromJson` like

```java
JsonUtils.fromJson("a", scala.reflect.Manifest.classType(LocalUser.class));
```

or

```java
JsonUtils$.MODULE$.fromJson("a", scala.reflect.Manifest$.MODULE$.classType(LocalUser.class));
```

Based on [Calling a Scala from Java Play Framework which takes a ClassTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582045/calling-a-scala-from-java-play-framework-which-takes-a-classtag)

Regarding `toJson` I can't see problems. Although if you call overloaded version of `toJson` with `Map` argument, maybe you'll have to convert between `scala.Predef.Map` aka `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and `java.util.Map`

[Convert Java Map to Scala Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918956/convert-java-map-to-scala-map)

[How can I convert Scala Map to Java Map with scala.Float to java.Float k/v conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583265/how-can-i-convert-scala-map-to-java-map-with-scala-float-to-java-float-k-v-conve)

By the way, `Manifest` is deprecated in favor of `ClassTag`/`TypeTag`

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html