# Converting Map[String, Double] to java.util.Map[String, java.lang.Double]

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I thought we can rely on implicit conversion which converts `scala.Double` to `java.lang.Double`. So I tried the following:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object Main extends App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val m = Map("10" -> 20.0)
    doSome(m.asJava) //error. Type mismatch found: java.util.Map[String,scala.Double]
                     //                  required: java.util.Map[String,java.lang.Double]
    doSome2(m.asJava)
  }
  def doSome(m: java.util.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.Double]) = println(m)
  def doSome2(m: java.util.Map[java.lang.String, Double]) = println(m)
}
```

Why doesn't it work? What would be the idiomatic way to perform such a conversion?

Answer (score 6):

You need the boxed version of `double`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

m.mapValues(Double.box).asJava
```

The implicits are able to convert a value of `Double` to `java.lang.Double`, but not a `Map[String,Double]` to `java.util.Map[String,java.lang.Double]`.

`String` requires no conversion because `String` *is* a `java.lang.String` while `Double` is a `double` (primitive).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for `String`, you don't need to do any conversion, but is not the case for `Double`. 
You can use the method `double2Double` which is defined in `Predef` to convert to java.double.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

m.map { case (k, v) => k -> double2Double(v) }.asJava
```

or another way is to do `asInstanceOf` to convert it to Java map directly.

Comment: `asInstanceOf` won't let you convert a Scala map to a Java map.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `scala.Double` is a primitive (equivalent to Java `double`) while `java.lang.Double` is a class. They are not at all the same thing. The `JavaConverters` converts between Java Map and Scala Map, not their contents. This works:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val m = Map("10" -> 20.0)
    doSome(mapConv(m))
    doSome2(m.asJava)
  }
  def doSome(m: java.util.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.Double]) = println(m)
  def doSome2(m: java.util.Map[java.lang.String, Double]) = println(m)

  def mapConv(msd: Map[String, Double]): java.util.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.Double] = {
    msd.map { case (k, v) => (k -> new java.lang.Double(v)) }.asJava
  }
}
```