# Returning typed collection from Scala 2.13 method to Java 8 caller

Tags: java, scala, function, scala-java-interop

I want to return `java.util.List<Integer>`s to the Java 8 code below instead of the `java.util.List<Object>`s that are returned from the following Scala 2.13.0 code. Both the Java and the Scala code could be modified to suit. I don't want to force any type conversions, for example no `(java.util.List<Integer>)` or `.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[Int]]` casts.

**`collections.FunctionConverterFromJava.scala`**

```scala
trait FunctionConverterFromScala {
  import java.util.{List => JList}
  import scala.collection._

  val intoEvenOdd: JList[Int] => (JList[Int], JList[Int]) = {
    import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
    javaList: JList[Int] =>
      javaList.asScala.partition(_ % 2 == 0) match {
      case (even: mutable.Buffer[Int], odd: mutable.Buffer[Int]) =>
        (even.asJava, odd.asJava)
    }
  }
}

object FunctionConverterFromJava extends FunctionConverterFromScala {
  import java.util.{function, List => JList}

  def reverse(string: String): String = string.reverse

  def zipChars(string: String): IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)] = string.zipWithIndex

  val intoEvenOddForJava: function.Function[JList[Int], (JList[Int], JList[Int])] = {
    import scala.jdk.FunctionConverters._
    intoEvenOdd.asJava
  }
}

object FunctionConverterFun extends App with FunctionConverterFromScala {
  val jList: java.util.List[Int] = {
    import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
    (1 to 10).asJava
  }
  println(intoEvenOdd(jList))
}
```

**Java program**

```java
import collections.FunctionConverterFromJava$;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FunctionConverterFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "Hello!";
        String reversed = FunctionConverterFromJava$.MODULE$.reverse(string);
        System.out.println("reversed = " + reversed);

        IndexedSeq<Tuple2<Object, Object>> zippedChars = FunctionConverterFromJava$.MODULE$.zipChars(string);
        System.out.println("zippedChars = " + zippedChars);

        List<Object> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
        Tuple2<List<Object>, List<Object>> list2 = FunctionConverterFromJava$.MODULE$.intoEvenOddForJava().apply(list1);
        System.out.println("list2 = " + list2);

        java.util.function.Function<List<Object>, Tuple2<List<Object>, List<Object>>> f = FunctionConverterFromJava$.MODULE$.intoEvenOddForJava();
        Tuple2<List<Object>, List<Object>> list3 = f.apply(list1);
        System.out.println("list3 = " + list3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484838/5205022) turns `java.util.List[scala.Int]` into `java.util.List<java.lang.Object>`. For example, `javap` output for `intoEvenOddForJava` is

```
public scala.Function1<java.util.List<java.lang.Object>, scala.Tuple2<java.util.List<java.lang.Object>, java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>> intoEvenOddForJava();
```

However, if we were to change from `scala.Int` to `java.lang.Integer` like so

```
object FunctionConverterFromJava extends FunctionConverterFromScala {
  ...
  val intoEvenOddForJava: function.Function[JList[java.lang.Integer], (JList[java.lang.Integer], JList[java.lang.Integer])] = {
    intoEvenOdd.asJava.asInstanceOf[function.Function[JList[java.lang.Integer], (JList[java.lang.Integer], JList[java.lang.Integer])]]
  }
}
```

then we avoid type erasure according to `javap` output

```
public java.util.function.Function<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>, scala.Tuple2<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>, java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>> intoEvenOddForJava();
```

Now from Java we can call as required

```
java.util.function.Function<List<Integer>, Tuple2<List<Integer>, List<Integer>>> f = FunctionConverterFromJava$.MODULE$.intoEvenOddForJava();
Tuple2<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> list3 = f.apply(list1);
System.out.println("list3 = " + list3);
```

which outputs

```
list3 = ([2],[1])
```

Now I understand that you wish to avoid `asInstanceOf`, however notice it would be hidden in the library `FunctionConverterFromJava`, that is, call-site would be clear of `asInstanceOf`. If you still wish to avoid `asInstanceOf` completely, then consider adding the following to `FunctionConverterFromScala`

```
val intoEvenOddAsJava: JList[java.lang.Integer] => (JList[java.lang.Integer], JList[java.lang.Integer]) = {
  import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
  javaList: JList[java.lang.Integer] =>
    javaList.asScala.partition(_ % 2 == 0) match {
      case (even: mutable.Buffer[java.lang.Integer], odd: mutable.Buffer[java.lang.Integer]) =>
        (even.asJava, odd.asJava)
    }
}
```

and then call `intoEvenOddAsJava.asJava` in `FunctionConverterFromJava.intoEvenOddForJava`.

That `asInstanceOf` hidden in library might be acceptable [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998096/5205022)

> ...the underlying representation of `Int` is `Integer` you can cast
>   directly to `java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]`

---

Addressing the comment, Eugene's answer [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57102366/5205022)

> ...how does it know
>   about Integer (via that `checkcast`) if generics are erased? The answer
>   is the optional `Signature` that is generated when A is compiled, or in
>   your cases:
>
> `()Lscala/collection/immutable/List<Ljava/lang/Object;>; //fooInt` 
>   `()Lscala/collection/immutable/List<Ljava/lang/Integer;>; // fooInteger`
>
> This `Signature` information is what is used by the compiler to enforce
>   type safety at callsites, via runtime checks; if this field would not
>   be present - that would have been impossible.

Comment: Yes, this works. **Suggestion**: add `import java.lang.{Integer => JInt}` **Question**: Why does `JList[JInt]` not encounter the same problem as `JList[Int]`?

Comment: Thanks for attempting to improve your answer. Yes, type erasure is somehow involved, however the level of answer you have provided is essentially "because type erasure" and I'd like a more specific answer. If the collection had a user-defined type (extending `AnyVal` or `AnyRef`) I expect the issue to return `Object`, unless a better understanding yielded a different incantation.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Please see edited answer with the link to extensive answer by Eugene.